# Css - how to add an image outside a text box (on the left side but touching the box)

Tags: css, textbox, alignment

On my website http://goo.gl/ok43H I'd like to add the small "+" icon next to each white text box (I made a mockup of what i'm trying to achieve here: http://goo.gl/ftRpZ ) but I have no idea how to do that.
What would be your suggestions?
Many thanks,

Here is the html code:

```
<div class="presentation-plusbox">
<p>Expertise dans l'industrie</p>
<p>blblablabla</p>
<p>blabla</p>
</div>
```

and here is the css code:
    .presentation-plusbox

```
{
    width: 500px;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    padding:10px;   
    margin-left:25%;
    color:#000000;
    margin-bottom:8px;
    opacity:0.95;
    filter:alpha(opacity=95); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: I assume you want the icon to be clickable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `:before` - http://jsfiddle.net/fgRRw/

```
div:before {
    content: "+";
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    background: orange;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    left: -30px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Just a note - `:before` is not supported in IE7 and below [**LINK**](http://caniuse.com/#search=before)

Comment: Looks good, although the + will not appear in older browsers (as you note) and is not rendered as an actual DOM element, so it cannot be interactive.

Answer (score 1):

Define your + box as a div inside of `.presentation-plusbox`

Also add `position: relative` to `.presentation-plusbox`

Then apply the following css to the plus box

```
.plusBox {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: -50px;
}
```

Of course, you'll need to adjust `top` and `left` to get it just right.

Comment: I think I will go for this solution http://jsfiddle.net/fgRRw/, but thanks a lot for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but that should work.

```
p { position: relative; }
p:after { 
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-image: url('image.url.goes.here.jpg');
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: -20px;
}
```

Comment: I think I will go for this solution http://jsfiddle.net/fgRRw/, but thanks a lot for your suggestion!